# Django Rest Frameworks, Nested many to many serialization

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I'm new to using DRF. I have a 2 layered many-to-many relationship I would like to be able to serve up.

```
# models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person,related_name='groups',blank=True)
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group,related_name='events',blank=True)
```

In my serializer I would like to be able to show in Person, which event they are attending.

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ( 'id', 'name', 'groups' )

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ( 'id', 'name', 'people' )

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    #not sure how to lookup the events related field here...
    events = EventSerializer(source='groups.name', many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ( 'id', 'name', 'groups', 'events')
```

However, I'm getting an error when I look up events. Is this lookup even possible?

Currently the output looks like this, I have groups mapped to events "party" but it says 'null':

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "mike",
    "groups": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "events": null
}
```

I'd would like the output to be a list of events. Like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "mike",
    "groups": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "events": [
        "party"
    ]
}
```

Also I've tried using depth=2 but it doesn't do anything for many to many fields.

Comment: you can use the depth option of a serializer to display nested relationship this is the simplest way but you have to omit the `groups = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)` and `events = EventSerializer(source='groups.name', many=True,read_only=True)`

Comment: can you provide the EventSerializer code?

Comment: Sure I'll add it to the main question

Comment: Is `class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ( 'id', 'name', 'groups', 'events')
        depth = 1`
wont work?